# How to fix black screen when switching to discrete graphics card (GPU)?

Tags: graphics, gpu, steam

Symptom: When I open any app that triggers my computer to switch to discrete graphics, such as Adobe Illustrator or games on Steam, my screen goes black (with a backlight). The only way to recover my screen is to either quit the app using the keyboard (if able) or reboot the mac.

I can also trigger the problem by switching to "Discrete Only" mode in gSwitch (which I installed only AFTER I started having the issue, so gSwitch is not itself the culprit).

Oddly, the discrete graphics card works normally shortly after a reboot. It starts acting oddly about a day after a fresh reboot. I have not been able to identify what triggers the graphics glitch.

Is there a way to "reset" my discrete GPU without rebooting each time?

System info:

- MacBook Pro (16-inch, 2019)
- 2.3 GHz 8-Core Intel Core i9
- 32 GB 2667 MHz DDR4
- AMD Radeon Pro 5500M
- macOS Monterrey 12.3

Comment: Discrete GPUs have a long history of failing on Mac laptops. I think you need to take this to an Apple Store or other hardware shop.